# Failed to read config values in java(null returned not value)

Tags: java

I have been developing a game(one of my first ^^) but have run into a problem with importing properties. Below I have posted all of the relative files and the problem I have hit - if anyone knows where I have gone and who I can fix it I would be very appreciative :)

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Here is my main class(Currently just for testing)

```
package game;

public class Main {

    //Setup
    static Settings settings = null;

    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("Main Started");

        settings = new Settings();
        String test = settings.getProperty("test");
        String hello = settings.getProperty("hello");

        System.out.println("Test: " + test);
        System.out.println("Hello: " + hello);
    }

}
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

This is the settings class to load the settings when called.

```
package game;

//Imports
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Settings {
    Properties config = new Properties();
    InputStream input = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");

    public Settings(){
        System.out.println();

    }

    public String getProperty(String key){
        String value = config.getProperty(key);
        return value;
    }

    public int getValue(String key){
        int value = Integer.parseInt(config.getProperty(key));
        return value;
    }

    public void close(){
        try {
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

This is the properties file(.properties)

```
#Test Strings
test = "this is a test"
hello = "Hello, World."

#Resolution Settings
width = 800
height = 600
scale = 1

#Cars
speed = 1
cars = 1
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

This is the console, where null is returned

```
Main Started

Test: null
Hello: null
```

Thanks for reading!!! I hope you can help :)

Comment: I don't see you setting the `config` variable (except to a new `Properties` object), but that is supposedly where you get the properties from. That might be why they're `null`.

Comment: Check the location of the "config.properties" file. I hope you already put that at right place and able to read the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should load the resource properly for `config` and `input` when initial your `Settings` object, example:

```
public class Settings { 

    Properties config = new Properties();
    InputStream input = null;

    public Settings(){
        input = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
        // or use input = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
        config.load(input)
    }

    .... // other of your functions
 }
```

And I think, the filename of properties should become a parameter to enhance the flexibility of `Settings` class, ex:

```
public Settings(String filename){
    input = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
    // or use input = new FileInputStream(filename)
    config.load(input)
}
```

and in Main:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println("Main Started");

    settings = new Settings("config.properties");
    String test = settings.getProperty("test");
    String hello = settings.getProperty("hello");

    // say you have another properties named config2.properties to read
    Settings another_settings = new Settings("config2.properties");
    String xxx = settings.getProperty("xxx");
    String yyy = settings.getProperty("yyy");
}
```

Comment: I have done this now, thank you for your response - this was my first post so good to know how helpful you guys are :)